# Sql to group by 36 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do you write sql to return back results grouped by a 36 hour time period. With the results returning back the starting date of the 36 hour period, which would be be midnight.

example data in table

```
> date                      count
>--------------------------------   
>2015-05-14 01:00:00         1 
>2015-05-15 02:00:00         2    
>2015-05-15 20:00:00         3 
>2015-05-16 03:00:00         4
```

results wanted returned

```
> date            count
>---------------------- 
>2015-05-14         3 
>2015-05-15         9    
>2015-05-16         4
```

Comment: your results don't match the example data. Also, let's see your attempt...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--Set up table and data
DECLARE @ATable TABLE ([date] DATETIME, [Count] INT)
INSERT @ATable( date, Count )
SELECT '2015-05-14 01:00:00', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-05-15 02:00:00', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-05-15 20:00:00', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-05-16 03:00:00', 4

-- Query
SELECT
  d.[date],
  ( -- This subquery returns the sum of counts for the 36 hours
    SELECT
      SUM(a.[count])
    FROM
      @ATable a
    WHERE
      a.[date] < DATEADD(hour, 36, d.[date])
      AND
      a.[date] >= d.[date]
  ) AS [count]
FROM
  ( -- This subquery returns a list of unique dates
    SELECT
      DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date]), 0) AS [date]
    FROM
      @ATable
    GROUP BY
      DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [date]), 0)
  ) AS d
ORDER BY
  d.date
```

Please note that your data and required results DO NOT MATCH, As you have been told repeatedly. The above yields the following results:

```
date                          count
----------------------- -----------
2015-05-14 00:00:00.000           3
2015-05-15 00:00:00.000           9
2015-05-16 00:00:00.000           4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results of each 36 hour period that *always* starts from the midnight, this is quite easy to solve by create a date table -- a table that contains a row for each day (for example period 1.1.2000 - 31.12.2099 or whatever is the biggest range you'll ever need)

You can then do just something like this (not tested, hopefully works)

```
select
  d.[date],
  (
    sum(x.[count]) 
    from yourtable x 
    where x.[time] >= d.[date] 
    and x.[time] < dateadd(hour, 36, d.[date])
  ) as [count]
from
  dates d
```

You can avoid creating date table by using for example a recursive CTE or other things like that, but I wouldn't really recommend that.